# How to perform multiple count analytics using django?

Tags: python, django

I have an analytics dashboard - basically it shows the overview of the data's. Lets say that we have a table named "Records"

In my analytics dashboard, i need to show various details about the records of particular user:

```
user = Records.objects.filter(id=pk)
```

By this we get all the records associate with the user, now to show various analytics like as follows,

```
Total Records,
Total Records by Today
Total Records by Week
Total Records by Month
Total Active Records // Records which has status == active
Total InActive Records // Records which has status == inactive
```

How to do all these ? While researching i found few options to follow,

**Option 1 : Do separate query for each of the need**
**Option 2 : Do fetch all the data's and perform the above calculations in view and send as context**

How to deal with these ? Am also planning to use charts

```
Class Records:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

Comment: Do you need the count of records or rows? 
`total_records = 100 `
or 
`total_records = record1, ... , record100`?

Comment: Could you share the `Records` model?

Comment: Total records as count like ```Records.objects.filter(id-pk).count()``` @RezaHeydari

Comment: Have edited, do check @NielGodfreyPonciano

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using a frontend library like [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) (which I highly recommend), you have two approaches here:

1. Create the data structure for each query on the backend and serve all the data at once to the front end

   - Advantages:

     - Once the data is available in the front end, rendering scripts will run much quicker (i.e. changing charts)
   - Disadvantages

     - Data may take longer to initialize as the backend is doing a lot at once
     - The backend code may become redundant or overly complex and difficult to manage
2. Create an endpoint on the backend and query it dynamically from the front end

   - Advantages:

     - The backend is doing less work for each individual request, so load times are faster
   - Disadvantages:

     - Users who constantly flip between charts may experience lag as they wait for each request to execute

Obviously, this is not an exhaustive list of the pros and cons of each option, though generally I opt for option 2 in my projects.

Comment: Using chart is not my main concern, my main questiion is about how to calculate these things and it should be based on each query for each need or single query and compute the results on view ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, [Do database work in the database rather than in Python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/optimization/#do-database-work-in-the-database-rather-than-in-python), unless you have budget-constraints on using the database service (though the work would then be shifted to your app worker). Since you are only interested with the number of items, you can just use [QuerySet.count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#count). See the [Field Lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) for reference of the queries made below.

```
from datetime import datetime, date

user_records = Records.objects.filter(owner=some_user)
today = date.today()

total_records = user_records.count()
total_records_today = user_records.filter(created_at__date=today).count()
total_records_week = user_records.filter(created_at__year=today.year, created_at__week=today.isocalendar()[1]).count()
total_records_month = user_records.filter(created_at__year=today.year, created_at__month=today.month).count()
total_records_active = user_records.filter(status="active").count()
total_records_inactive = user_records.filter(status="inactive").count()
```

Or you can also manually perform the tally on all of the records:

```
for rec in user_records:
    if rec.created_at.date() == today:
        total_records_today += 1
    if rec.created_at.date().isocalendar()[1] == today.isocalendar()[1]:
        total_records_week += 1
    ...
```

Or:

```
total_records_today = len(list(filter(lambda rec: rec.created_at.date() == today, user_records)))
total_records_week = len(list(filter(lambda rec: rec.created_at.date().isocalendar()[1] == today.isocalendar()[1], user_records)))
...
```